# How do I make JQuery event work for 2 classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.logger').bind('click',function(){
        alert('we will log that the user shared something');
        return true; //keep going, pretend nothing happened.
    });

    $('.share').bind('click',function(){
        window.open('blah');
        return false; 
    });
});
</script>
<a href="#" class="share logger">Share this</a>
```

I want to be able to trigger BOTH the logger and the share functions. But right now, only the share function is triggered. If I comment share function, then the logger function works fine.

I've also tried to change the "class" so that logger is before share.

Comment: In which browser did you test it? It worked in Chrome and Firefox for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fjRUY/

Comment: the code you posted is working for me :S

Comment: work for me too (chrome). there must be mistake somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `return false;` in an event handler that stops the event propagation, that is why the other handler is not triggered. If you just want to stop the default action, use `event.preventDefault()`.

This [article](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) does a good job explaining the concept:

> First off, return false is actually
>   doing three very separate things when
>   you call it:
>
> 1. event.preventDefault();
> 2. **event.stopPropagation();**
> 3. Stops callback execution and returns
>      immediately when called.
>
> “Wait a
>   minute,” you cry! **I only needed to
>   stop the default behavior! I don’t
>   need these other two items**… I think.
>
> The only one of those three actions
>   needed to cancel the default behavior
>   is **preventDefault()**. Unless you mean
>   to actually stop event propagation
>   (bubbling), using return false will
>   greatly increase the brittleness of
>   your code

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is downvoted. Anyone cares to explain?

Comment: `return false` prevent propagation but doesn't stop other callbacks to be fired on the same element. For the purpose `stopImmediatePropagation` should be used

Comment: Yes, this is buried in the clunky JQuery doco. I was about to post an answer much the same as Raul's first paragraph and thought I'd look it up in the JQuery doco first and it's really not obvious. It says returning false does `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`, and the page on `stopPropagation()` explicitly says that it doesn't stop other handlers on the same element from running *without even mentioning that* `stopImmediatePropagation` *exists*.